# any update on making pyinstaller compile a python file that uses sympy?

Tags: pyinstaller, sympy

I tried to convert a small .py file to .exe on windows but found that pyinstaller do not work when sympy is used.

Googling around, this shows it is old problem.

https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/16865

https://gitmemory.com/issue/sympy/sympy/16865/494288181

My question is: Any one knows of an update on this problem and any work around possible?

Here is the set up and a MWE. Using windows with conda 4.8.2 and Python 3.7.6. Compiling this ex5.py file, gives recursion error

```
from sympy import *

print("1")
```

And now

```
 pyinstaller --onefile  ex5.py
```

Gives

```
 .....
 File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 271, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 281, in generic_visit
    self.visit(value)
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 271, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 281, in generic_visit
    self.visit(value)
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 271, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 275, in generic_visit
    for field, value in iter_fields(node):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Commenting out the line which imports sympy, the file compiles OK.

Comment: This is a bug in PyInstaller we (The PyInstaller devs) are working to fix. See https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4406 for more details.

Comment: @Legorooj this is good news! It will be very good to be able to compile python with sympy to a .exe. This can open the door to many interesting applications.

Comment: @Legorooj I am having hard time following that thread you gave. Could you please indicate which version of python or PyInstaller would one expect it to work with sympy? This way I can just keep checking when that is out. Thanks.

Comment: the next 2 releases. I am currently working on tracking down the source of the issue (There are 11000 lines of logs to read). Expect it in either PyInstaller 4 or 4.1. Both will be out by christmas, the first (4.0) in april-june probably.

Comment: @Legorooj thanks for the update. I hope you can find a fix for this.